# ajax call for apache fileupload in jsr 286

Tags: java, ajax, portlet, jsr286

I am using apache fileupload in the form for portlets. I noticed that the class PortletFileUpload serves only action requests. I am using JSR286 and I want to call serveresource method whenever I click submit button. Is this possible or is there any work around to achieve this ?

Comment: You can follow the article [link](http://www.softwareorbit.com/documentation/portlets/using-resource-url-for-ajax) to send request to serveResource method from your jsp. Not sure if typecasting ResourceRequest object to ActionRequest would help.